# What are some examples of overlapping subproblems that don't have an optimal substructure thereby we cannot solve it using dynamic programming?

Tags: dynamic-programming, divide-and-conquer

I believe problems like quicksort and other divide-and-conquer are problems that have optimal substructure but do no have any overlapping subproblems. I hope I'm correct here. But I'm unable to think of some examples of overlapping subproblems that don't have an optimal substructure.

Comment: You mean like 3-SAT?

Comment: See [strongly NP-hard problems](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_NP-completeness). These do not admit efficient dynamic programming solutions assuming $P\ne NP$

Comment: Even the knapsack problem has overlapping subproblems but it is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard.